# Sum column based on values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

```
     NAME    CATEGORY  RNA
     Banana  Fruit      27
     Apple   Fruit      27
     Banana  Fruit      28
     Apple   Fruit      28
     Orange  Berry      29
     Orange  Berry      29
```

I'm trying to sum the RNA column if the name's column value (within the same category) is different in the previous row with the same RNA, else null. For example, the first two rows become

```
     Banana     Fruit     54
```

Answer (score 0):

A try with your data adjusted a bit to have a little bit diverse in scenario.
Using the `rlied` from `data.table` in combination with `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
df <- tribble(
~NAME,    ~CATEGORY,  ~RNA,
"Banana",  "Fruit",      "27",
"Apple",   "Fruit",      "27",
# Wonder if this case would ever occur in your real data
# Where There is another Banana appear after Apple with same RNA
"Banana",  "Fruit",      "28",
"Apple",   "Fruit",      "28",
"Banana",   "Fruit",     "28",
"Orange",  "Berry",      "29",
"Orange",  "Berry",      "29"
)

df %>%
  # convert RNA to number
  mutate(RNA = as.numeric(RNA)) %>%
  # using rleid to group them by same Category/RNA consecutively.
  group_by(grp = rleid(RNA, CATEGORY)) %>%
  summarize(NAME = first(NAME),
    CATEGORY = first(CATEGORY),
    RNA = sum(RNA),
    .groups = "drop")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    grp NAME   CATEGORY   RNA
* <int> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 Banana Fruit       54
2     2 Banana Fruit       84
3     3 Orange Berry       58
```

Answer (score 0):

Retaining "Name" can be misleading/ incomplete? - you may want to summarize by "category" only using aggregate:

```
a <- letters[1:10] 
b <- sample(LETTERS[1:3],10, replace = T) 
c <- rpois(10,2.2) 
dfa <- data.frame(a,b,c)

aggregate( c ~ b, data = dfa, sum)
```

Numbers may vary:

```
> aggregate( c ~ b, data = dfa, sum)
  b  c
1 A 20
2 B  5
3 C  5
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this will serve the purpose

```
df %>% group_by(RNA, CATEGORY) %>%
  mutate(d = cur_group_id(),
         name2 = lag(NAME, default = "NAME"),
         d2 = (name2 != NAME)) %>%
  group_by(d, CATEGORY) %>%
  summarise(NAME = first(NAME),
            d2 = ifelse(prod(d2) == 1, 1, NA),
            RNA = sum(RNA)* d2) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-d2, -d)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  CATEGORY NAME     RNA
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1 Fruit    Banana    54
2 Fruit    Banana    56
3 Berry    Orange    NA
```

df taken

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  NAME   CATEGORY   RNA
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1 Banana Fruit       27
2 Apple  Fruit       27
3 Banana Fruit       28
4 Apple  Fruit       28
5 Orange Berry       29
6 Orange Berry       29
```